# List of workday dates from current and next week

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, iteration

Here is the deal: I need to fill up an array with workday dates(Mo-fr) from now and until the end of next week. For example:

Date today: Wed 13 dec

Output:

```
workdayArray{
   [0] => 2013/12/13 00:00:00   (Wed)
   [1] => 2013/12/14 00:00:00   (Thur)
   [2] => 2013/12/15 00:00:00   (Fri)
   [3] => 2013/12/18 00:00:00   (Mo)
   [4] => 2013/12/19 00:00:00   (Tue)
   [5] => 2013/12/20 00:00:00   (Wed)
   [6] => 2013/12/21 00:00:00   (Thur)
   [7] => 2013/12/22 00:00:00   (Fri)
}
```

Here is what i've tried:

```
//Our array we want to populate     
NSMutableArray *ScheduleDays = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Setting timezone
NSDateFormatter *dt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dt setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];

//Setting today's date and weekday        
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
gregorian.firstWeekday = 2;
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:today];
int weekday = [comps weekday];

//hardcoding iterations needed to fetch all dates       
int counter=7;
switch(weekday){
    case 1: counter=13; break;
    case 2: counter=12; break;
    case 3: counter=11; break;
    case 4: counter=10; break;
    case 5: counter=9; break;
    case 6: counter=8; break;
    case 7: counter=14; break;
}

//Populating ScheduleDays while skipping Saturday and Sunday
NSDate *date = today;
for(int x=0;x<counter;x++){
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *formatWeekday = [gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
    int weekday = [formatWeekday weekday];
    if (weekday!=1 & weekday!= 7) {
        [ScheduleDays addObject:date];
    }
    date = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*1];
}
```

*"It works, what is the problem?"* 
When hardcoding iterations needed and weekdays to be skipped, it seems to be a very sloppy code(i think). I'm trying to figure out how design an efficient method, without hardcoding iterations based on weekday etc. Any help or ideas on this design issue would be great.

Comment: NSCalendar & NSCalendarComponents.

Comment: You *do* know how to find the documentation, right?

Comment: Of course, that is not the problem. I'm just trying to figure out how design an efficient method, without hardcoding iterations based on weekday etc. 

I realize I should have stated this in my question, and will rephrase. Any help or ideas with this design issue would be great.

Comment: Also I have added an example to show my pain here, quit a lot of code for such a simple problem.

Comment: You have NSDateComponents already.  Don't increment the NSDate object itself, use NSCalendar dateByAddingComponents.  You could skip the weekend by running off an array of 2..6 for the weekday, though that's as messy as the if.  Your switch statement could be replaced with an appropriate expression using modulo arithmetic, though.

Comment: You don't need to keep creating the NSCalendar.  Just creating one at the top of the routine is sufficient.